# For each individual id, filter rows that have consecutive values in the year column

Tags: r, for-loop, sequence

I want to create a balanced panel data from the dataframe below:

```
id  program_year  value
1     2007         1
1     2008         1
1     2009         1
1     2010         1
1     2011         1
1     2012         1
1     2013         0
2     2007         0
2     2008         1
2     2009         1
2     2010         1
2     2011         1  
2     2012         1
2     2013         1
3     2007         1
3     2008         0
3     2009         1
3     2010         1
3     2011         1
3     2012         1
3     2013         1
```

For each `id`, I want to select *5* rows that have **consecutive** `value == 1` in the `program_year` column.

The expected output should look like:

```
id  program_year  value
1     2007         1
1     2008         1
1     2009         1
1     2010         1
1     2011         1
2     2008         1
2     2009         1
2     2010         1
2     2011         1  
2     2012         1
3     2009         1
3     2010         1
3     2011         1
3     2012         1
3     2013         1
```

I have explored with `lead()` and `lag()` but without any success. The next step after getting the desired output is to index the years to make dataframe a balanced panel.

Comment: What are you intending to do? Usually a "balanced panel" has **the same** time points (e.g. years) for each ID. It does not mean just same number of observations for each ID.

Comment: Once I get the same number of obs for each ID, I will index periods for each ID, so it will be a balanced panel. I'm trying to evaluate a policy with a staggered diff-in-diff model (Callaway-Sant'Anna estimator [link](https://bcallaway11.github.io/did/articles/did-basics.html))

Comment: Thanks for clarification, please see new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75921586/6574038) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you needed:

```
Data <- "id  program_year  value
1     2007         1
1     2008         1
1     2009         1
1     2010         1
1     2011         1
1     2012         1
1     2013         0
2     2007         0
2     2008         1
2     2009         1
2     2010         1
2     2011         1  
2     2012         1
2     2013         1
3     2007         1
3     2008         0
3     2009         1
3     2010         1
3     2011         1
3     2012         1
3     2013         1"

DF <- read.table(text = Data, header = TRUE)


library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  arrange(id, program_year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter((program_year - lag(program_year)) >= 1) %>% 
  mutate(consecutive = program_year - row_number()) %>%
  group_by(id, consecutive) %>%
  filter(n() >= 5) %>%
  slice_head(n = 5) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(id, program_year, value)
```

which returns the below:

```
# A tibble: 14 × 3
  id program_year value


  <int>        <int> <int>
 1     1         2008     1
 2     1         2009     1
 3     1         2010     1
 4     1         2011     1
 5     1         2012     1
 6     2         2008     1
 7     2         2009     1
 8     2         2010     1
 9     2         2011     1
10     2         2012     1
11     3         2009     1
12     3         2010     1
13     3         2011     1
14     3         2012     1
```

modified the answer to meet your condition `where value == 1`

Comment: I have sorted the year and ID to ensure that you should get consecutive years. let me know if that help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response but this is not the output that I am looking for. For  each `id` I want to get the first 5 `years` rows where `value == 1` consecutively.

Comment: modified... please check..

Comment: If you look at `id` == 3, you will see the year values are not consecutive. The year for `id 3` should be from 2009-2013.

Comment: What package should i use to run lag? It is not working for me. I tried using the `Hmisc` package to run `lag()` but it did not create 5 rows for each `id`. In your code too, you can see that `id 1` has 5 rows, `id 2` and `id 3` has 4 each, while my desired output requires 5 consecutive year rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a solution using `dplyr::consecutive_id()` and per-operation grouping. Make sure you’re using the most recent version of dplyr.

```
library(dplyr) # >= v1.1.0

dat %>%
  mutate(c_id = consecutive_id(value), .by = id) %>%
  filter(value == 1, n() >= 5, .by = c(id, c_id)) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 5, .by = id) %>%
  select(!c_id)
```

```
   id program_year value
1   1         2007     1
2   1         2008     1
3   1         2009     1
4   1         2010     1
5   1         2011     1
6   2         2008     1
7   2         2009     1
8   2         2010     1
9   2         2011     1
10  2         2012     1
11  3         2009     1
12  3         2010     1
13  3         2011     1
14  3         2012     1
15  3         2013     1
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is here to create a two dummy columns: first a row number column and then a dummy group by column. Finally you will deselect the dummy columns from the result.

df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(program_year) %>% filter(value!=0) %>% mutate(row_num=row_number(),dummygroup=program_year-row_num)%>% group_by(id,dummygroup) %>% arrange(id,desc(program_year)) %>% filter(n()>=5,row_number()<=5)

Answer (score 0):

In a `by`, for each ID we could first `subset` for non-zero values, create a group `u` for sets of consecutive values, and `subset` `x` for maybe that group yielding `which.max` number of observations in a `table`. Next we `head` the list-like `"by"` object for the `min`imum number of observations and finally `rbind`.

```
by(dat, dat$id, \(x) {
  x <- subset(x, x$value == 1)
  u <- cumsum(c(1, diff(x$program_year)) != 1) + 1
  tbl <- table(u)
  subset(x, u == which.max(tbl))
}) |> {\(.) lapply(., \(x) {
  m <- min(sapply(., nrow))
  transform(head(x, m), period=seq_len(m))
})}() |>  ## or `tail` instead of `head`
  do.call(what='rbind')
#      id program_year value period
# 1.1   1         2007     1      1
# 1.2   1         2008     1      2
# 1.3   1         2009     1      3
# 1.4   1         2010     1      4
# 1.5   1         2011     1      5
# 2.9   2         2008     1      1
# 2.10  2         2009     1      2
# 2.11  2         2010     1      3
# 2.12  2         2011     1      4
# 2.13  2         2012     1      5
# 3.17  3         2009     1      1
# 3.18  3         2010     1      2
# 3.19  3         2011     1      3
# 3.20  3         2012     1      4
# 3.21  3         2013     1      5
```

Giving the largest possible subset of consecutive observations given the IDs, albeit as asked in OP with **non-matching** years, but with a new period variable added.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), program_year = c(2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L), value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```